# Board SMD Component Identification

Tags: identification

I don't recognize this component, maybe some of you will. I measure 10.6 ohms across it. I believe it might be an inductor or filter bead, but i need to be sure.
As you can see in the picture, it says 105K , 4083, and that is it.

I'll point out that this board is no longer working, and i'm looking for a faulty component, so the measurment i took (10.6 ohms) could be the result of measuring a component that no longer works as it should.

Note: in the circuit, there are no parallel components with this item, so i believe the measurement to be accurate

[image]

Comment: It's a power inductor made by EPCOS. It's similar to [this](http://picclick.co.uk/68uH-2220-SMD-Inductors-EPCOS-B82442A1683K-SMT-Inductor-131424525059.html), but probably not identical. I cannot tell the size from your photo.

Comment: That appears to be a 1 micro (something) 10% device but I don't have time to search for the manufacturer.

Comment: Probably not the source of your problem, since it does not look burned and measures a reasonable resistance. Look for a fuse and/or semiconductor, most likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that it might be something similar to the following: [SMT Inductors](https://en.tdk.eu/inf/30/db/ind_2008/b82442h.pdf)

I do not know exactly what the parameters are for this device, but I would guess it is a 1mH, 10% tolerance device with a 12 Ohms DC resistance.

To make sure it is the correct device, look on TDK website for Fixed Inductors.  Here is the package that I found online for it:

[image]

Any inductor will have some series resistance associate with it.  This is the reason why you would read 10.6ohms across the inductor.